# vstest.console.exe fails to start tests

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've been trying to use the new 'vstest.console.exe' that comes with VS2010 (in my case I'm using the version that comes with the Visual Studio 2012 test agent software).

However, when I specify to launch tests, like this:

> vstest.console.exe "MyTest.orderedtest"

I get the message returned "Starting test execution, please wait", then the task finishes - but my UI tests don't start. And I don't know if there are any results saved anywhere, if there even are any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vstest.console.exe doesn’t create the TRX file by default.
Results would be sent only to console. If TRX is needed, user has to enable it explicitly by specifying /logger:trx

EX- Vstest.console.exe abc.dll /logger:trx

Answer (score 2):

Tests weren't starting because my test DLL's (Coded UI tests) were referencing VS2010 DLL's.

vstest.console.exe doesn't appear to give any output to explain why the tests didn't start, and there is also no indication of where result logs are saved. The command-line options [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) doesn't help here too.

Answer (score 0):

For running any ordered test using vstest.console following command can be used.

e.g. if you want to execute mytest.orderedtest then run following command

**vstest.console mytest.orderedtest /Logger:trx**

Run from the folder where the ordered test is present.